# kibana visualization and object array

Tags: kibana

Is kibana support object array? Is there any way to see the fields of an array in a pretty way in Kibana or it isn't supported?

Comment: Did you find a solution for your problem ?

Comment: @tejas_spy007, Sorry for late reply. I was out for a few days. 
No, as per https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/998 they are not supporting the Object Array in Kibana 4. I did it differently. Instead sending an object array I seperated it in a string ob.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/998 they are not going to support Object arrays in Kibana 4

Answer (score 0):

This is something we needed too, and since an official solution doesn't appear to be on the horizon we've developed a Kibana plugin to address this.

It works in Kibana 5.x+ by injecting entries into the index pattern's field list which match the dot notated path of the array (or any object in your data). With the field entry in place, you now have the ability to define a field format for it. None of the built in formatters expect a JSON object, so the plugin includes one which covers the basic needs.

https://github.com/istresearch/kibana-object-format

Comment: How to use this plugin for elk docker based image. Is there any steps to install it on docker image and I'm using 7.3 kibana version but still see this issue