# Pretty way of displaying array and array of objects in kibana

Tags: javascript, json, elasticsearch, data-visualization, kibana

I am new to kibana and I have just completed building a dashboard in kibana with elasticsearch data.
The array and array of objects in kibana are just showed stringified and not in a pretty way.

Example of Array:

```
"tags": [
        "Anthem",
        "Healthcare"
      ]
```

But in kibana is shown in the following way

```
["Anthem","Healthcare"]
```

Example of Array of objects

```
  "observations": [
      {
        "category": [
          "phishing"
        ],
        "impact": "phishing url",
        "observedAt": 1406564412,
        "description": "Phishing Other",
        "sourceConfidence": 7,
        "source": "phishtank.com",
        "sourceMaliciousness": "medium"
      }
    ],
```

But in kibana is shown in the following way

```
{"category":["phishing"],"impact":"phishing url","observedAt":1406564412,"description":"Phishing Other","sourceConfidence":7,"source":"phishtank.com",...
```

I want to display tags as clickable anchors which trigger a new search or atleast in a prettier way than just showing an array.
Is there any way this can be achieved ?

Comment: An answer to your question might be found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30910970/kibana-visualization-and-object-array